# Constructors and multiple classes communicating in C#

Tags: c#, forms, class

I have two classes in my windows form application in C#. I learned in this forum how to define instances of form in each class and vice versa. Here is the code now:

Form1:

```
 namespace WinFormApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Class1 cls1;
        Class2 cls2;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            cls1 = new Class1(this);
            cls2 = new Class2(this);

        }
    }
}
```

Class1:

```
using WinFormApp1;
class Class1
{
    private Form1 Frm1;

    public Class1(Form1 parent)
    {
        Frm1 = parent;
    }
}
```

Class2:

```
using WinFormApp1;
class Class2
{
    private Form1 Frm1;

    public Class2(Form1 parent)
    {
        Frm1 = parent;
    }
}
```

It works perfectly, but now I want to call class1 methods in class2 and vice versa. What is the best way of doing this? Should I define another constructor in each class without input argument like below, or there is any better way of doing this? Is there any way I can use the existing constructor like in above to define instances of class1 in class2 and vice versa?

Class1:

```
using WinFormApp1;
class Class1
{
    private Form1 Frm1;

    public Class1(){}

    public Class1(Form1 parent)
    {
        Frm1 = parent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can do this... however, do you really want to? Why do these class instances need to call in to one another? Once you get your head around your current problem, you might want to think about decoupling strategies, to avoid the spaghetti mountain that will arise out of this tight-coupling. Events are a good place to start.

Comment: @spender: thanks for your comment. I have couple of hardware and I am reading them and sending commands to them. That's why I put their methods in separate cs files. Do you have any example or link about events and how they can be of any help in regard to my question?

Answer (score 2):

You can either create an instance of one of the classes in another, or use static methods to call code without needing a reference.

Either way, if these classes are sharing a ton of code you may consider merging them in the first place.